# Tutorial screen where users can interact following my instructions

Tags: android, screen

I need a screen where I'll guide the users what to do and they should follow my instructions. This screen only appears as firt-time-use screen and never appears again. I found an app named Cover Lockscreen. Its tuorial screen is just the right thing I need.

Please take a look at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3QH139_mjilNjF0cDBKdlp5TGc/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried using framelayout (set its background with an image) and putting some interactive things so users can play with. But the problem is that the screen resolution will change with different devices and firstly this makes my background change, sometimes distorted. Secondly as the background changes, the interactive area changes too and I can't control whether the area is still in the right place with the background anymore.

I have also tried Showcase library and it's not enough. There must be some ways to do this I believe.

**EDIT :** Ok sorry I wasn't clear enough. Let me say this again:

I got a nice picture, its resolution is 1080x1920. I'll use it as the background of the acitivity. The picture content is something like the one I posted below. As you can see, there's a hand holding the "phone" in the picture. I want to ask users to draw an "S" on the "screen" of that "phone".

To do that, I create a new activity. The main layout will be framelayout. I set the background of framelayout with the picture (1080x1920 resolution). I'll set the theme of this activity to noTitleBar and Fullscreen so the picture will not be distorted. Then I put GestureOverlayView (because we can draw and recoginze gesture on it) on the framelayout. I set the margin left and top, width and height with some **fixed values** in dp so that it is "on" the "phone" of the background. If everything works as it's planned then the result is that GestureOverlayView will lay on the screen of the phone (I use red color to indicate the area of GestureOverlayView)

**PROBLEM:**

I can't handle picture distortion. As my origin picture is 1080x1920 so other screen resolutions like 480x800 (Nexus S) 800x1280 (Nexus 7) will cause distortion,... and of course with tablet, it's even worse (my current solution to tablets is...forcing the screenOrientation to be portrait). If the background gets distorted then the area of the phone will **change**. So the margin_left, margin_top, width, height of GestureOverlayView will not be correct anymore. I can't use 9-patch cuz my picture is pretty complicated.

**Result:**

Devices with 1080*1920 and 720*1280 will have a nice background with the correct interactive area. Meanwhile, devices with other resolutions will have a distorted background and the interactive area maybe somewhere but not on the "phone" of the picture I set as the background.
[image]

Comment: such kind of concept or screen called as on highlighting

Comment: let me know if this get solved am also looking for same

Comment: Your problem of the background changing or being distorted is something you, as an android dever, need to get used to and provide the correct image sizes for *all* the devices you wish to provide a good experience for. This is the same for the layout. If someone is in landscape, or on a tablet, or both you will want to make layouts for these cases. It's just something you have to do.

Comment: Will something like this help? https://github.com/justinmwarner/GestureTutorial

Comment: @redGREENblue sorry but...no :(

Comment: Add the layout file you're using. Please tell us whether or not you understand that screen sizes/densities changing by device is a *well-known* issue and that it is fairly easily handled. I don't understand the specific issue here. This kind of behavior is normal; you're certainly not the first person to come across this. Explain *exactly* what you mean and why you're unable to deal with it, methods you've tried, and examples of at least one specific situation. "On this device using this bucket it looks good but that one with that bucket doesn't. Tried to fix by..., but that doesn't work."

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I editted my question. Please take a look at my EDIT, PROBLEM and RESULT:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by following these steps:

1. make the desired view in the background activity communicate their x,y coordinates(location on screen) to the tutorial activity.
2. based on the co-ordinates received,the tutorial activity will draw its control.

To get x,y location of each view at runtime use the following method.

> public void getLocationOnScreen (int[] location)
>
> Added in API level 1 Computes the coordinates of this view on the
>   screen. The argument must be an array of two integers. After the
>   method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order.
>
> Parameters location   an array of two integers in which to hold the
>   coordinates

For more info refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29)